# How do I add on multiple $_POST['row'] and variables?

Tags: php, html, syntax, variables

I am struggling to find out the syntactically correct way in which to add on more variables and rows to these statements:

/* WANT TO ADD ON FIVE MORE $_POST[''] */

```
if(isset($_POST['check_prof']) && $_POST['check_prof'] == 'checked') {
$check_prof = "checked";
}else{
$check_prof = "unchecked";
}
```

/* SAME HERE, WANT TO ADD THE OTHER FIVE IN HERE AS WELL */

```
$query = "UPDATE `Users` SET `check_prof` = '" . $check_prof . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $auth->id . "' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $auth->refresh();
    }
```

Comment: To make sure I'm getting this straight, you want to be able to grab a series of $_POST variables, then put them all into the same SQL statement? So your SQL might become something like, 

`UPDATE Users SET check_prof = 'checked', check_student = 'checked' WHERE id = 'whatever' LIMIT 1` (backticks removed from SQL for SO formatting)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$fields = array('check_prof', 'check_this', 'check_that', 'check_whatever');

foreach($fields as $field){
    isset($_POST[$field] && $_POST[$field] == 'checked')){
        $$field='checked';
    } else {
        $$field='unchecked';
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `Users` SET `$field` = '" . $$field . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $auth->id . "' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $auth->refresh();
}
```

By the way, instead of storing "checked" and "unchecked" in your database (as a varchar) you can store it as type tinyint(1) and just use a 0 or a 1. It will take up way less space.

Another thing, this will do a separate query for each field. It's more efficient to write one query to do the changes for all fields if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you mean, try this:

```
<?php
$arr = array('check_prof' => 'unchecked',
            'check_student' => 'unchecked');
foreach($arr as $field => $checked) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field]) && $_POST[$field] == 'checked') {
        $arr[$field] = 'checked';
    }
    // I don't know where $auth is coming from
    $query = "UPDATE `Users` SET `$field` = '" . $arr[$field] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $auth->id . "' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($query,$connection);
    $auth->refresh();
}
?>
```

You would simply need to add fields as needed to `$arr` for it to loop through.

Comment: I just want to add on multiples...if(isset($_POST['check_prof']) && $_POST['check_prof'] == 'checked') {
$check_prof = "checked";
}else{
$check_prof = "unchecked";
} 
f(isset($_POST['check_blog']) && $_POST['check_blog'] == 'checked') {
$check_blog = "checked";
}else{
$check_blog = "unchecked";
} 

but don't know the proper syntax to add them on to the same statement, just want to add on multiple variables and post values etc

Comment: another words, what you see in the original question is just for check_prof, but want to add on check_blog,check_question etc... to the same statment